# Getting error when executing the dynamic query in sql server 2008 to fetch the full name of from table @tblName = 'Cutomer_List'

Tags: sql-server

When I am executing this dynamic query via this, I am trying to fetch the complete name of customer `(First_Name + Last_Name)`.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Code is here:

```
 Set @tblName ='Customer_List'
    Exec (N'Select First_Name'+' '+'Last_Name from'''+ @tblName+'''
                 where Customer_Id in ('+ 'cast(1000 as nvarchar(10))' );
```

I am getting this error:

```
 (1 row(s) affected)
                        Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
                        Incorrect syntax near 'dbo.Customer_List'.
                        Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
                        Incorrect syntax near 'dbo.Customer_List'.
                        Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
                        Incorrect syntax near 'dbo.Customer_List'.
                        Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
                        Incorrect syntax near 'dbo.Customer_List'.
                        Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
                        Incorrect syntax near 'dbo.Customer_List'.
                        Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
                        Incorrect syntax near 'dbo.Customer_List'.
```

Comment: When debugging dynamic sql, the first thing you should do is PRINT your sql string so you can see what you are trying to execute.   The error usually then becomes glaringly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Set @tblName ='Customer_List' Exec (N'Select First_Name'+' '+'Last_Name from '+ @tblName+' where Customer_Id in ( cast(1000 as nvarchar(10) ))' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this . 
1) Add space after `FROM`. 
2) Add the `)` bracket in `(10)))`
3) Remove the `''` arround the table name.

```
DECLARE @tblName AS VARCHAR(100)

 Set @tblName ='TempTable'
    Exec (N'Select First_Name'+' '+'Last_Name from '+ @tblName+'
                 where Customer_Id in ('+ 'cast(1000 as nvarchar(10)))' );
```

Answer (score 0):

try following query:

```
DECLARE @sql as VARCHAR(1000)
SET @sql = 'Select First_Name + '' ''+ Last_Name from '+ @tblName + ' where Customer_Id in (' + CAST(1000 AS VARCHAR(1000)) + ')'
Exec (@sql)
```